# GRUB installation failed Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, xubuntu

My computer is an old Lenovo a57. It gives this error when I tried to install Xubuntu 20.04. I used manual partitioning during the installation to create `/boot`, `swap`, `/home`, and root `/` partitions, but it still gives an error. I  tried to install GRUB with a live CD with Boot-Repair, but it didn't work.

When I try to load the system the only thing that appears is a black screen with `Read Error`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the OS has likely been installed, the issue could be caused by one of three issues:

1. The cable connecting the disk to the motherboard is loose
2. The OS was installed for UEFI, but your system requires BIOS mode to boot
3. The disk is failing

For the first item, check the cables. For the second, you’ll want to reinstall and make sure it’s done with a “Legacy Boot” setup. For the third, you will need to boot with a Live USB or DVD, open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and perform the following:

1. If needs be, determine which device you’ve installed Ubuntu onto:

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```

   You will see something like `/dev/sda1`
2. Check the disk for errors:

   ```
   sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1
   ```
3. Do the same for any other disks or partitions you may have.
4. Once done, reboot.

So long as the disks are good, you should be able to boot. If you continue to see issues, the drive is likely bad.